# How do I load a text file in my program without it being located outside of the sources folder?

Tags: java, text-files, scanning

So up until now I can only get access to a text file in my java project by placing it outside of the sources folder and outside of any package.
I don't think that's how it is supposed to be and I am wondering how else I can load the text file if I put it in a package?
Here's what I did for loading the text file, which worked but only since the file is located outside of the sources folder

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("saveScores.txt")); //writing on it with a bufferedwriter
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader("saveData.txt")); //reading the data with a scanner
```

Comment: The only thing that's supposed to be in the sources folder is sources, not resources. Resources (text files, images, etc.) are supposed to be on their own resources folder, as configured in your IDE, and you are supposed to read them not as a file but as a resource.

Comment: `String appPath = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();`. It should hold the parent directory of where your JAR file was started from. If used in the IDE it should hold the Project directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend to choose a distribution tool (Gradle, Maven, Ant...). These Frameworks/Tools usually create destinct directories. For example a **"source"** or **"src"** directory, where your source code is supposed to live.
One of the other directories they will create is something like a **"resource"** or **"res"** directory, where static resources (like a ".txt" file) are supposed to live in.

Distribution of software is not that trivial. You could do it all by your own, but I wouldn't recommed it. You have to invest a little work to learn using one of these Frameworks/Tools if you want to distribute your code. Choose wisely from the 3 top dogs in the Java world (Personal opinion: Choose Gradle):

1. [Gradle](https://gradle.org/)
2. [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/)
3. [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/)

**If** you want to walk down that road to do it all by your self, follow best practises:

1. Create a new directory where **all** your resources should live in
2. Add this directory to your classpath
3. Get the resources during runtime via `getResourceAsStream`.

   - Java will start looking on the classpath for the files you're asking for by searching through all directories/subdirectories you added on your classpath. If Java can't find it, an exception is thrown.
4. Compile your finsihed Programm with this **"resource"** directory. Since all files/directories in a compiled JAR, are automatically on the classpath, your code will still work.